# Question about summation Chain Rule of Entropy and simplification of summation in the proof

Tags: probability, summation, entropy

So I was going through the proof on page 23 of https://www.icg.isy.liu.se/courses/infotheory/lect1.pdf, and I'm not quite understanding how the double summation simplifies to a single summation . The part where it goes

\begin{align}
H(X, Y) &= -\sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log p(x) - \sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log p(y|x) \\
&= \sum_{x} p(x) \log (p(y) - \sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log p(y|x) 
\end{align}

If I assume independence between $x$ and $y$ then the double summation $-\sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log p(x)$ would simply as follows

\begin{align}
-\sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log p(x) &= -\sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x) p(y) \log p(x) \\
&= -\sum_{x}  p(x)\log p(x) \sum_{y} p(y)   \\
&= -\sum_{x}  p(x)\log p(x) * 1 \\
&= H(X) \\
\end{align}

but how would I show this without assuming independence? Is there a trick to simplifying $-\sum_{x} \sum_{y} p(x,y) \log p(x) $ ?

Comment: Have you tried to figure out (from the definitions of marginal distribution) what $\sum_{y} p(x,y)$ is?

Comment: @ZoltanZimboras I suppose that would give me the marginal $P_X(x)$. Oh so $\sum_X \sum_Y P(x,y) \log P(x)$ turns into $\sum_X P(X) \log P(x)$ ?

Comment: Exactly, so you get the desired result  immediately.